# Why do I get "identifier is undefined" or "not available" when inspecting a Rust variable in the VSCode debugger?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust

I've set up the Visual Studio Code debugger and run the following program.

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let mut chars = "test".chars();
    match chars.next() {
        Some(c) => {
            println!("What is the value of c, here?");
            if c == 'c' {
                println!("c");
            }
        }
        None => {}
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at line 6, and look in the Variables and Watch panes, c does not evaluate, but rather passes the following message: `identifier 'c' is undefined` using cppvsdbg on Windows, or `<not available>` using lldb on Linux. I've confirmed that this happens both on Linux and Windows builds, for the current stable compiler version.

I've also added the following to Cargo.toml to no avail:

```
[profile.dev]
opt-level = 0
debug = true
```

For reference, here is my launch.json file, needed for the VS Code compiler:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/test.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Replace "(Windows) Launch" with your OS of choice.

Why is this the result? Is there a fix, or are there some compiler options that should be added?

Comment: Not sure if it would work but potentially redeclaring `let c = c;` might make that variable available to the debugger?

Comment: @Frxstrem Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that, and it did not seem to make a difference. Either way, I would love to find a solution that does not require extra boilerplate.

Comment: LLDB doesn't yet support a number of Rust concepts. It can't understand enums, and apparently can't understand `char` either.

Comment: @PeterHall That is unfortunate. Are you aware of another GNU toolchain that supports these features? Or barring that, any clue if there's a roadmap for this type of support?

Comment: `rust-gdb` is able to print the value: `$ rust-gdb target/debug/pr`, then `(gdb) br main.rs:6`, `(gdb) run`, and when it stops `(gdb) print c` shows: `$1 = 116 't'`.

Comment: Possibly related: [rls-vscode#509 `Option` variables show "<not available>" even when clearly set](https://github.com/rust-lang/rls-vscode/issues/509)

Comment: I'm not necessarily able to dig deep into this right now, but this is possibly related too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621130/how-can-i-inspect-variable-values-while-debugging-msvc-abi-rust-programs?rq=1

Comment: Orthogonal to your direct question, but an `if let` would be more idiomatic than a `match` in this code.

Comment: Have you ever run any rust code on vscode before or it's the first time? I mean, if it's the first time, there may be some problem setting up the extension.

Comment: Same experience as OP on mac

Comment: Please change the title to include that fact that its VSCode and not Visual Studio.

Comment: Good call, thanks @RefaelSheinker

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not reproducible with recent release of CodeLLDB.

`CodeLLDB v1.7.0`
`rust : 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)`
`vscode: v1.67.0`

Everything works as expected the debug view shows

```
iter: {end:0x000055555559105f}
c: 't'
```

Upgrading the codelldb to specified version will resolve the issue.